# WHERE IN clause in Android sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, where-clause, clause

I can't get WHERE IN clause to work on android SQLite database.

Is there any way to execute a statement like this in android? :

```
SELECT body FROM table1 WHERE title IN ('title1', 'title2', 'title3')
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? What is does your code look like?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `TextUtils.join(",", parameters)` to take advantage of sqlite binding parameters, where `parameters` is a list with `"?"` placeholders and the result string is something like `"?,?,..,?"`.

Here is a little example:

```
Set<Integer> positionsSet = membersListCursorAdapter.getCurrentCheckedPosition();
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer position : positionsSet) {
    ids.add(String.valueOf(membersListCursorAdapter.getItemId(position)));
    parameters.add("?");
}
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
    SharedUserTable.CONTENT_URI,
    SharedUserTable._ID + " in (" + TextUtils.join(",", parameters) + ")",
    ids.toArray(new String[ids.size()])
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. I didn't know I had to supply a separate placeholder ('?') for each parameter in the "IN" clause. I thought a single placeholder with a single String parameter (multiple values joined in it) was enough.

Comment: is this how you did it? String where = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " IN (? ?)";

Answer (score 11):

You will have to use the `rawQuery` method:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT body FROM table1 WHERE title IN ('title1', 'title2', 'title3')");
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was trying to it this way before, but apparently I had some syntax issues...

Comment: As rawQuery is prone to SQL injection if we pass dynamic parameters, can you suggest to get similar results without rawQuery ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a content provider you can use the query function as such:

```
getContentResolver().query(URI,new String[] {"body"}, "title IN ?", new String[] {"('title1','title2','title3')"}, null)
```

Note that I have not tested this, but according to the documentation, this should work.

Comment: this doesn't work in Android 4.0.4 - SQLite wrapper classes throw exceptions

Comment: This won't work. It will get translated into `SELECT body FROM table1 WHERE title IN '('title1', 'title2', 'title3')'`. Notice `'`s around the whole argument part.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this

```
Cursor mCursor = SQLiteDatabase.query(true, "Name of table","String array of selection columns","title  in ('title1', 'title2', 'title3')", null, null, null, null, null);
if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419062/286878). It helped me in the similiar case.

```
String[] names = { "name1", "name2" }; // do whatever is needed first
String query = "SELECT * FROM table" + " WHERE name IN (" + makePlaceholders(names.length) + ")";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, names);
```

The main point here is to provide variable question-mark placeholders (?) to match your IN clause items. And of course - argument for them as String array.

Comment: do you know how to do this with an array of INT[]? My column onto which the IN applies is of type INTEGER.

Comment: you have to convert your arbitrary array to String[]

Answer (score 1):

You need to write rawquery that way -

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT colunm1 FROM table WHERE colunm2 IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Cristian answer:
While his answer will work, you should try to use the correct way of querying:

`db.rawQuery("Select * from table1 where title = ?", new String[]{param1});`

This approach can also be used with WHERE IN clause, but the passed string has to be in format of 'asd','zxc','qwe'

Like this:

```
String param1 = "\'asd\',\'zxc\',\'qwe\'";
db.rawQuery("Select * from table1 where title in (?)", new String[]{param1});
```