# IN clause and placeholders

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm attempting to do the following SQL query within Android:

```java
    String names = "'name1', 'name2";   // in the code this is dynamically generated

    String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (?)";
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, new String[]{names});
```

However, Android does not replace the question mark with the correct values.  I could do the following, however, this does not protect against SQL injection:

```java
    String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (" + names + ")";
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
```

How can I get around this issue and be able to use the IN clause?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

A string of the form `"?, ?, ..., ?"` can be a dynamically created string and safely put into the original SQL query (because it is a restricted form that does not contain external data) and then the placeholders can be used as normal.

Consider a function `String makePlaceholders(int len)` which returns `len` question-marks separated with commas, then:

```java
String[] names = { "name1", "name2" }; // do whatever is needed first
String query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    + " WHERE name IN (" + makePlaceholders(names.length) + ")";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, names);
```

Just make sure to pass exactly as many values as places. The default maximum [limit of host parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) in SQLite is 999 - at least in a normal build, not sure about Android :)

---

Here is one implementation:

```java
String makePlaceholders(int len) {
    if (len < 1) {
        // It will lead to an invalid query anyway ..
        throw new RuntimeException("No placeholders");
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 2 - 1);
        sb.append("?");
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(",?");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the (only) way to use parameterized IN () queries in SQLite and pretty much any other SQL database.

Comment: Using this method, I augmented the ContentProvider I used and in the query() method added logic to test for the presence: "IN?" and if found, does a count of the occurrence of "?" in the original selection, compared with the length of arguments passed, assembles a "?, ?,...?" for the difference and replaces the original "IN?" with the generated question mark collection. This makes the logic available almost global and for my uses it seems to be working well. I did have to add some special provisioning to filter empty IN lists, in those cases, the "IN?" is replaced with "1" for now.

Comment: The silly thing about this is, of course, that if you are going to make your own String with N question marks, you might as well just encode the data directly. Assuming it's sanitized.

Comment: This whole `makePlaceholders` could be replaced with `TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(len, "?"))`. Less verbose.

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT url FROM tasks WHERE url=?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?`

Answer (score 9):

Short example, based on answer of user166390:

```
public Cursor selectRowsByCodes(String[] codes) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = {COLUMN_NAME_ID, COLUMN_NAME_CODE, COLUMN_NAME_NAME, COLUMN_NAME_PURPOSE, COLUMN_NAME_STATUS};
        String sqlTables = "Enumbers";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);

        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, COLUMN_NAME_CODE+" IN (" +
                        TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(codes.length, "?")) +
                        ")", codes,
                null, null, null); 
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Sadly there's no way of doing that (obviously `'name1', 'name2'` is not a single value and can therefore not be used in a prepared statement).

So you will have to lower your sights (e.g. by creating very specific, not reusable queries like `WHERE name IN (?, ?, ?)`) or not using stored procedures and try to prevent SQL injections with some other techniques...

Answer (score 5):

As suggest in accepted answer but without using custom function to generate comma-separated '?'. Please check code below.

```
String[] names = { "name1", "name2" }; // do whatever is needed first
String query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    + " WHERE name IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(names.length, "?"))  + ")";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, names);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextUtils.join(",", parameters)` to take advantage of sqlite binding parameters, where `parameters` is a list with `"?"` placeholders and the result string is something like `"?,?,..,?"`.

Here is a little example:

```
Set<Integer> positionsSet = membersListCursorAdapter.getCurrentCheckedPosition();
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer position : positionsSet) {
    ids.add(String.valueOf(membersListCursorAdapter.getItemId(position)));
    parameters.add("?");
}
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
    SharedUserTable.CONTENT_URI,
    SharedUserTable._ID + " in (" + TextUtils.join(",", parameters) + ")",
    ids.toArray(new String[ids.size()])
);
```

Comment: What if one of the "parameters" need to be null?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could use android's native way of querying instead of rawQuery:

```
public int updateContactsByServerIds(ArrayList<Integer> serverIds, final long groupId) {
    final int serverIdsCount = serverIds.size()-1; // 0 for one and only id, -1 if empty list
    final StringBuilder ids = new StringBuilder("");
    if (serverIdsCount>0) // ambiguous "if" but -1 leads to endless cycle
        for (int i = 0; i < serverIdsCount; i++)
            ids.append(String.valueOf(serverIds.get(i))).append(",");
    // add last (or one and only) id without comma
    ids.append(String.valueOf(serverIds.get(serverIdsCount))); //-1 throws exception
    // remove last comma
    Log.i(this,"whereIdsList: "+ids);
    final String whereClause = Tables.Contacts.USER_ID + " IN ("+ids+")";

    final ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(Tables.Contacts.GROUP_ID, groupId);

    int numberOfRowsAffected = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbAdapter.getWritableDatabase());
        try {
            numberOfRowsAffected = db.update(Tables.Contacts.TABLE_NAME, args, whereClause, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dbAdapter.closeWritableDB();


    Log.d(TAG, "updateContactsByServerIds() numberOfRowsAffected: " + numberOfRowsAffected);

    return numberOfRowsAffected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not Valid**

```
String subQuery = "SELECT _id FROM tnl_partofspeech where part_of_speech = 'noun'";
Cursor cursor = SQLDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM table_main where part_of_speech_id IN (" +
                        "?" +
                        ")",
                new String[]{subQuery}););
```

**This is Valid**

```
String subQuery = "SELECT _id FROM tbl_partofspeech where part_of_speech = 'noun'";
Cursor cursor = SQLDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM table_main where part_of_speech_id IN (" +
                        subQuery +
                        ")",
                null);
```

**Using ContentResolver**

```
String subQuery = "SELECT _id FROM tbl_partofspeech where part_of_speech = 'noun' ";

final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1","2"};
final String selection = "_id IN ( ?,? )) AND part_of_speech_id IN (( " + subQuery + ") ";
SQLiteDatabase SQLDataBase = DataBaseManage.getReadableDatabase(this);

SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.setTables("tableName");

Cursor cursor =  queryBuilder.query(SQLDataBase, null, selection, selectionArgs, null,
        null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (${names.joinToString(separator = ",") { "?" }})"
val cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, names.toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the `Stream` API for this:

```
final String[] args = Stream.of("some","data","for","args").toArray(String[]::new);
final String placeholders = Stream.generate(() -> "?").limit(args.length).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
final String selection = String.format("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN(%s)", placeholders);

db.rawQuery(selection, args);
```