# android sqlite query optimisation

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite db with about 400 000 entries. To query the db I am using the following method:

```
public double lookUpBigramFrequency(String bigram) throws SQLException {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
        double frequency = 0;
        bigram = bigram.toLowerCase();

        String select = "SELECT frequency FROM bigrams WHERE bigram = '"
                + bigram + "'";

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(select, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {

            if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                frequency = Double.parseDouble(mCursor.getString(0));
            } else {
                frequency = 0;
            }
        }

        return frequency;


    }
```

but it takes about 0.5 sec to retrieve a single entry and having few queries, it builds up and the method is executing for 10 secs. How to speeed it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, use an INDEX

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

in your case that will be something like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_bigram ON bigrams (bigram)
```

Secondly, use '?' instead of literal query. It helps sqlite for caching requests:

```
String select = "SELECT frequency FROM bigrams WHERE bigram = ?";
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(select, new String[]{ bigram });
```

Thirdly, I trust query is more efficient than rawQuery:

```
mCursor = dq.query("bigrams", new String[] { "frequency" }, "bigram = ?",
          new String[]{ bigram }, null, null, null, null);
```

Fourthly, you can query several values at once (not compatible with point 2):

```
SELECT frequency FROM bigrams WHERE bigrams IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Fifthly,  you don't need to open your database every time. You should consider leaving it open.

### Edit

After seeing this question [IN clause and placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders) it appears you can combine 2 and 4 after all (not sure it is useful, though)

Comment: #1 and #5 are the most significant in terms of performance; #2 is important to avoid SQL injections, and simply looks better

Comment: +1 for the non-literal querys. -1 for assuming that `query()` would be faster then `rawQuery()`.

Comment: it improved the speed by about 10-20 ms but that's still not enough

Comment: Well actually I messed up the indexes at first. Did it again and it helped. Thanks

Comment: Yes, using selection args works a bit faster. every millisecond count

Answer (score -1):

Always use transaction mechanism when you want to do lots of database operations

```
public static void doLotDBOperations() {
    try {
        // Code to Open Database

        // Start transaction
        sqlDb.beginTransaction();

        // Code to Execute all queries

        sqlDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // End all transaction
        sqlDb.endTransaction();

        // Code to Close Database
    }
}
```

Comment: which would be relevant for write operations.