# Sqlite UPDATE with parameterised IN (...) clause

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app I'm working with sqlite database - and I hit a strange issue.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
_id   field1   field2   status
---   ------   ------   ------
 1    value    value    ...
 2    value    value    ...
...
```

At one place, I need to update some rows to set them to another status, so I'm trying

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("status", STATUS_SENT);
Set<Integer> ids = datasource.getCompletedIds();
String idparam = TextUtils.join(",", ids);
int cnt = db.update(TABLE_ORDERS, cv, "_id in (?)", new String[] { idparam });
Log.d("db", "updated " + cnt + " rows");
db.close();
```

However nothing gets updated - and `db.update` returns 0.  What am I missing?

Comment: It took me a minute to find since "in" is a [**horrible** search engine parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+[sqlite]+in)... but: [Android/SQLite IN clause and placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7418849/1267661).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not happy recommending *not* using parameters, but it this case, it's actually easier than formatting all those `?` markers (and with plain integers, just as safe):

```java
db.update(TABLE_ORDERS, cv, "_id IN (" + idparam + ")", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you must list *one* insertion character `?` for *each* id in your Set...
A popular fix is to write a quick utility to add the appropriate number of `?`s based on the Set's size.