# Android SQLite column index

Tags: android, sqlite

I am quering to my SQLite data base to get records using IN operator

```
myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artist_id IN (?)", values);
```

but i am getting some SQLite exception. i did not understand what the problem is 
when my database has 1 record which was returned by this query then it was prefect, but when i have 2 or more records in my database to return by this query it is throwing some exception
that exception is

```
SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong with this query

thanks...

Comment: I think, `IN` requires `values` with "," separator.

Comment: you have to have a separate '?' for each value in `values` array. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders

Comment: Your are right @David M

Comment: your are right  @Chintan Rathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest like this

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
// build "SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artist_id IN "
query.append('(').
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    query.append(values[i]);
    if (i != values.length - 1) {
        query.append(',');
    }
}
query.append(')');

myDataBase.rawQuery(query.toString(), null);
```

Comment: Thanks man i have tried the same approach to solve this issue :)