# Pass Array as Arguments to query a database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to fetch rows from database where column named "Uid" matches a few options. Since the number or arguments is dynamic, I need to pass it the arguments as array.

```java
public Cursor Topicsname(List list) {
    SQLiteDatabase sq = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = "";
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        where = where+"Uid"+" ="+list.get(i).toString()+"";
        if (i!=(list.size()-1)) where=where+" or ";
    }
    Cursor cursor = sq.query("Topics", new String[] {"Main_Topics"},
        where, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

But I get row count as 0. Here "Topics"- Table Name, "Main_Topics" -Column name I need to fetch, "Uid" column name that  matches the list value.

Comment: Found Answer using this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders

Comment: well you cannot use arrays but use sets in sql to query , in your where clause .