# How to get SQLite database Column values as List in android

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I have three column, first id, second title and third body.

Like this

```
id         title         body
1           t1           b1
2           t2           b2
3           t3           b3
```

So, I want to get title and display in list with listview and if  I click t2 title then display body of respective clickable title.

What i did.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public Cursor retriveTitle(String [] title) {
        Cursor c = null;
        c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "select id,title from book,", title);
        return c;
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
private void displayTitle() {
        try {
            myDataBase = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT b.id, b.title FROM book b  ",   new String[] { ""  });

        String test=cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex("title"));
        //How to display title of book in listview
    }
```

getting this:

```
01-18 14:20:03.401: E/AndroidRuntime(6704): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

I am using already database file, according to this blog post: [**Using your own SQLite database in Android applications**](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT b.id, b.title FROM book b",null);
   curosr.moveToFirst();
    String test=cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("title"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should use a "where" statement

```
c = myDataBase.rawQuery("select id,title from book where title=?", title);
```

Of course you want to pass a certain number of arguments

```
c = myDataBase.rawQuery("select id,title from book where title in (?, ?, ?)", new String[]{title1, title2, title3});
```

But then if the number of title can vary, you will need to dynamically create a string with enough question marks. See this post

[IN clause and placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders)

If you still get en error, maybe providing more log could help. Also if the lo say what line fails, tell which one it is. we can't see line numbers here

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it worked out for me. In an other class, I have created a method of List type and added the column id & the name of the item in the list from the sqlite database.

Here's the piece of code to retrieve the column id of the selected item.

```
    public List<String> list;
    adapt = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_inner_view, list); //custom adapter
    listTask.setAdapter(adapt);

    listTask.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long l) {

       Integer id = list.get(position).getId();
       //position is the position of the item in the list.
      }
   });
```

Result: the item is at 3rd position in the list. Its database column_id (auto increment) value is 12 because I have deleted previous items. So the result you expect is 12, which is the value of variable id.

If you don't understand this fully, it may be because I haven't posted my entire code. But I'll help you out with your problem.