# Android:SQLite - Querying an Array in SelectionArgs as well as other string values

Tags: android, sqlite

I had the following code for Content Resolver Query:

```
String selection = Columns.NAME + "=? and " + Columns.AVAILABILITY + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = { name, true };
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Columns.URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

This code was working fine since I had only one name, but now I have an array of names which are to be added to cursor only if their availability is true. ie, my scenario is I want to put those rows in the cursor which have any of the names (present in the array) only if their Availability is true.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you getting any error??

Answer (score 8):

SQL has the [IN operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) for this:

```java
String selection = Columns.NAME + " IN (?,?,?) AND" +
                   Columns.Availability + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { name[0], name[1], name[2], true };
...
```

---

If the array size is not predetermined, you have to construct the `selection` string and the `selectionArgs` array dynamically:

```java
String selection = Columns.NAME + " IN (" + makePlaceholders(names.length) + ")" +
                   " AND " + Columns.Availability + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[names.length + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    selectionArgs[i] = names[i];
selectionArgs[names.length] = true;
...
```

with the function `makePlaceholders` copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419062/11654):

```java
String makePlaceholders(int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 2 - 1);
    sb.append("?");
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        sb.append(",?");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, the array size and values are not predetermined. can u please explain how can I do it now.

Comment: [Java: convert List<String> to a join()d string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string); [How to add new elements to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)

Comment: it's work with me, thank you <3 but I removed final line "selectionArgs[names.length] = true;" because it return an error