# Out of range error by query more then one images from gallery

Tags: android, sqlite

When `String[] ids` has one argument, query return data, when more then one, get error:
`Cannot bind argument at index X(number of arguments) because the index is out of range.`  The statement has 1 parameter.

```
Cursor  cr = ctx.getContentResolver().query( 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    null, 
    "_id = ?",
    ids,
    orderBy
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"_id = ?"
```

This construction serves to reserve place for one parameter. If you want to select items with several ids you better use the folowing:

```
"_id IN (?,?,?..?)"
```

Here is the answer about parametrization of this type of query: [IN clause and placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders)