# Subquery in android sqlite, not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
// My getBus Function 
Cursor getBus(String source, String dest)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT b.BusName FROM BusTable b, (SELECT Route , RBusName FROM RouteBusTable WHERE Route IN ("+source+")) b1, (SELECT Route , RBusName FROM RouteBusTable WHERE Route IN ("+dest+")) c WHERE b.BusName IN (b1.RBusName) AND b.BusName IN (c.RBusName)", new String [] {});

     return cur;
 }

// Retreiving it like this
Cursor a = dbHelper.getBus("1", "12");

    a.moveToFirst();
    while (!a.isAfterLast())
    {
        String Name = a.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this, "Stops Are "+ Name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        a.moveToNext();
    }
```

It stops the app. What I doing wrong there??
Is there any mistake in subquery or retrieving??

Comment: 1. Post strack trace. 2. Try put apostrophes around your strings, e.g. `IN ('"+source+"')) b1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to quote `source` and `dest` by ' symbol like this:

```
"... WHERE Route IN (\'"+source+"\') ..."
```

If problem is here then you should think how to avoid this with multiple values in `source` and `dest`. 
In your particular case you should form it correctly like `source = "\'1\', \'2\'"` or use recommendation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders)

P.S. If it doesn't work please provide logcat error message and resulting query (at runtime)