# Simple solution for selecting multiple elements using WHERE OR in greenDAO?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, greendao

I've got a list of primary keys and I need these elements from my greendao database.

The most trivial method would be to query each object idividually and inserting it into a list:

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjectByIds(List<String> ids) {
    List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    for (String id : ids) {
        QueryBuilder<MyObject> queryBuilder = myObjectDao.queryBuilder();
        MyObject myObject = queryBuilder.where(MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(id)).unique();
        result.add(myObject);
    }

    return result;
}
```

However this seem quite ineffective since it would have to do ids.size() queries. A single query with multiple OR statements would be better. However, since the [whereOr()](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/QueryBuilder.html#whereOr%28de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition...%29) and [or()](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/QueryBuilder.html#or%28de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition...%29) methods only except 2 or more parameters you'd have to make quite a few IF ELSE statements to catch lists with 0, 1 or 2 ids:

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjectByIds(List<String> ids) {
    QueryBuilder<MyObject> queryBuilder = myObjectDao.queryBuilder();

    if (ids.size() == 0) {
        List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        return result;
    } else if (ids.size() == 1) {
        return queryBuilder.where(MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(ids.get(0))).list();
    } else if (ids.size() == 2) {
        queryBuilder.whereOr(MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(ids.get(0)), MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(ids.get(1)));
        return queryBuilder.list();
    } else if (ids.size() >= 3) {
        queryBuilder.whereOr(MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(ids.get(0)), MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(ids.get(1)), getWhereConditionsEqIdRefFromThirdElementOn(ids));
        return queryBuilder.list();
    }
}

private WhereCondition[] getWhereConditionsEqIdFromThirdElementOn(List<String> ids) {
    WhereCondition[] whereConditions = new WhereCondition[ids.size() - 1];
    for (int i = 2; i < ids.size(); ++i) {
        whereConditions[i] = MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(ids.get(i));
    }
    return whereConditions;
}
```

Honestly, this might be faster but it still seems quite ugly to me. Is there another way? Or do I have to make a raw query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Dragon Bozanovic. `GreenDAO` does have `IN` operator for this purpose.

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjectByIds(List<String> ids) {
    return myObjectDao.queryBuilder()
             .where(MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.in(ids)).list();
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I was only looking at the functions of the `QueryBuilder` when the `Property` itself had the solution. [link] (http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/Property.html#in%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but this looks like a by the book example for using [`in` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/android-sqlite-in-clause-and-placeholders).

Comment: Yes GreenDAO does have IN Operator, I have added the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this:

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjectByIds(List<String> ids) {

    List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    QueryBuilder<MyObject> queryBuilder = myObjectDao.queryBuilder();
    for (String id : ids) {
        queryBuilder.whereOr(MyObjectDao.Properties.Id.eq(id));
    }

    return queryBuilder.list();
}
```

According to the documentation [here](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/QueryBuilder.html#whereOr(de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition...)), it seems that each whereOr function adds the given conditions to the previous where clause using an logical OR. It might be necessary to add a initial where clause before the for.

Comment: This won't do the trick since the `whereOr` function requires at least two parameters. Thats exactly the problem I needed to solve...