# find missing rows of a sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

**Problem description:** 
I have a table which `primary key` is `id` and I also have an `array` of `id`s. The array contains `id`s from the table but some `id`s of the table may be missing in the array. I need to `delete` the rows of which `id`s are missing in the array.

**My approach:** 
I fetch all the `id`s from the table and sort the two array. Then comparing two array I find out the missing `id`s and deleted corresponding `row`s.

Is there any better( easy and/or efficient) way to do this?

Comment: have you tried using IN clause? I think it might be faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/in-clause-and-placeholders

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin I didn't yet. Thanks for suggestion. I need to delete the missing ones. How IN can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a delete statement like the following:

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3, ...)`