# WHERE and IN clauses combined in android SqLite

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, where-clause, where-in

I was trying to retrieve data from sqlite. I want to get data from table 'tbl_expense', I have few conditions:

1. Date - Date filtering
2. Expense type(here frequencyID) may fall in multiple categories.

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_OFFICE_EXPENSES + "WHERE " + DATE + " > ? AND (" + DATE + " < ? AND " + FREQUENCY_ID + " IN ?)" + " ORDER BY " + DATE + " ASC", new String[]{dateFrom, dateTo, frequencyString});

my frequency String : ('1', '2', '3')

my StackTrace: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_expense_office WHERE date_paid > ? AND (date_paid < ? AND frequency_id IN ? ) ORDER BY date_paid ASC, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)`

NB: I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418849/in-clause-and-placeholders) before asking my question, My bad, I couldn't find anything helpful from that question. How do you relate my question to the linked question? @CL

Comment: is `date` is column name in your table ?

Comment: yes, date is a filed..

Comment: use different Name then

Comment: why you suggesting that?

Comment: becoz date is preserved word in sqlite

Comment: ooh, thanks,
But still same error pops!

Comment: check the white space is added properly

Comment: am I using the IN clause correctly?

Comment: try this `SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_OFFICE_EXPENSES + " WHERE  " + DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  " + FREQUENCY_ID + "  IN ?" + " ORDER BY  " + DATE + " ASC", new String[]{dateFrom, dateTo, frequencyString});`

Comment: remains same after trying your code, am i using the IN cluase correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118977/discussion-between-m-d-and-bachu).