# SQLite query with selection arguments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following SQLite query:

```
ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<>();

// adding Long values to idList

SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

final String whereClause = COLUMN_DEVICE_ID + " IN (?)";
final String[] whereArgs = new String[]{TextUtils.join(", ", idList)};

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DEVICES, null, whereClause, whereArgs,
    null, null, null);
```

Executing this query results in an empty `Cursor`.

It seems like the reason of the problem is the `whereArgs` `String` does not get inserted into the `whereClause`.

I debugged the code and noticed that the `mQuery` field of the `Cursor` is initialized to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_devices WHERE device_id IN (?)
```

Why is the `?` not getting replaced with the `whereArgs`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you get when you execute TextUtils.join(", ", idList)?

Comment: similiar question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7419062/4665578

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem with the following:

```
final String args = TextUtils.join(", ", ids);
final String whereClause = String.format(COLUMN_DEVICE_ID + " IN (%s)", args);

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DEVICES, null, whereClause,
    null, null, null, null);
```

Although i'm not sure how safe this is compared to the `?` + `whereArgs` approach (regarding SQL injection).