# JDBC to android.sqlite: SELECT/DELETE … WHERE field IN (?)

Tags: android, jdbc, android-sqlite

I am just porting some JDBC code (intended for use with HSQLDB) to Android’s own SQLite implementation. I have a snippet where I delete records based on a particular field matching one of the values in a `String[]` array in my Java code.

Here is the JDBC code for the `DELETE` statement:

```
String[] ids = getIdsSomehow();
PreparedStatement stmtD = db.prepareStatement("delete from message where id in (unnest(?))");
Array delIdArray = stmtD.getConnection().createArrayOf("VARCHAR", ids);
stmtD.setArray(1, delIdArray);
stmtD.execute();
stmtD.close();
```

Another snippet does a `SELECT` instead of `DELETE` and has the values in a `List<String>` instead of an array.

How would I accomplish this with the methods offered by `SQLiteDatabase`, preferably in a way that does not open up any SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main “ingredients” to make this work with HSQLDB over JDBC, namely the `unnest()` function of the DBMS, and the ability to pass array values to SQL statements, are not available with the `android.sqlite` stack, making a workaround necessary:

```
String[] ids = getIdsSomehow();
String whereClause = "id in (" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(ids.size(), "?")) + ")";
db.delete("message", whereClause, ids);
```

This builds a where clause à la `id in (?,?,?,?)` with the correct number of question marks.

For the selection, use `rawQuery()` with a `SELECT` statement built in the same manner. The `List<String>` can be converted to an array like this:

```
ids.toArray(new String[]{})
```

Input came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419062/2703209) and its comments.