# Dynamic query with content resolver using 'IN' clause

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to get a list of songs that matches a list of media Id's using content Resolver.

I have followed this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684127/15985008) to query items dynamically with content resolver

I am trying to query a list of songs that matches a list of id's passed.

E.G

*SELECT FROM MUSIC DATABASE WHERE _ID = {12, 13, 14, 15, 16}* -<< *This is dynamic, not fixed. could be empty or could be more.*

So, I want this to return a list of song attributes with those id.

**MusicDatabase**

```
fun getSongsInPlaylist(songIds: List<Long>): List<Songs> {

    val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(
        ",", Collections.nCopies(songIds.size, "?"))+")"
    val songList = mutableListOf<Songs>()
    val collection = Utility.sdk29AndUp {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    } ?:  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    for (i in songIds.indices) selectionArgs!![i] = songIds[i]


    //Get songs from provider
    context.contentResolver.query(
        collection,
        projection,
        selection,
        arrayOf(selectionArgs.toString()),
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER //Sort in alphabetical order based on display name.
    ).use { cursor ->
        if (cursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {

            do {
     }
```

**MusicViewModel**

```
 fun doGetAllSongsInPlaylist(songIds: List<Long>){

    val permissionGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    if (permissionGranted){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val songs = songsInPlaylistDatabase.getSongsInPlaylist(songIds)
            _songsInPlaylist.value = Resource.success(songs)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
 args.playlist.playlistId?.let { roomPlaylistViewModel.doGetAllSongsInPlaylist(it) }
    roomPlaylistViewModel.songsInPlaylist.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ songs->
        for (songId in songs){
            songId.songId.let { it1 ->
                if (it1 != null) {
                    songIdArray.add(it1)....//I am getting songId's and saving in an array
                }
            }
        }

   
  viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                
            playlistViewModel.doGetAllSongsInPlaylist(songIdArray)...//I am passing the song Id's stored in array here
           
                playlistViewModel.songsInPlaylist.collect{ result ->
                    when(result.status) {
                        Status.SUCCESS -> {
                            result.data?.let { songs ->
                                Log.e("lisx", songs.toString())
                            }
                        }
                        Status.ERROR -> Unit
                        Status.LOADING -> Unit
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am getting an error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters**

Comment: If you had a fixed list. Then how would your selection look like?

Comment: something like MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=${id}"

Comment: That does not help. And i see no list. Tell what it would become for a fixed list like  {12, 13, 14, 15, 16}. Post the string value. No code.

Comment: The problem is what to use as selectionArgs in the query

Comment: Ca be. But as you ask for an dynamic array you suggest you know what to do for a static. So please tell.