# Scanning different memory types in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-mediascanner, android-memory

I have some queries which may be useful to others too.
In android 4.0 onwards ,

1)how to check whether external sd card support is there or not ?

2)How to run Mediascan forcefully both internal and external memory ?

3)How to Mediascan only sd card or internal memory?

Comment: from `adb shell` run `mount` for a full view of what storage is mounted where on your device.

Comment: Thanks , but i mean programmatically

Comment: Yes you can run `mount` from your app and get the result string , have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3350332/1531054).

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question. But I tried giving a new response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on developer.android.com.

To check external memory is available (taken from developer.android.com):

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

To read internal files use `context.fileList();` see more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList%28%29).

**Edit**

I'm not sure what you want with 2 and 3. You can use mediascan to many things but using it just for using it sounds unproductive. For that I'd recommend @Singularity advice. There is a post [here about using mediascan for pdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10384080/969325).