# Searching the entire storage for media files or file types - android

Tags: android, search, storage, media

I've been searching for hours, including stackoverflow and on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com), but can't seem to find an answer:
I'm working on my first big project. I've decided to write my own media player. 
I'm looking for a way to index all the media files on the entire storage (as any good player does) and then break them down by file type (mainly audio or video).

1. How do I search the entire storage? This obviously needs to be fairly quick so that I can populate the list quickly enough so that it feels to the user like it happens without lagging. Is there any way to do this w/o recursion (I can't seem to be able to wrap my mind around recursions...)?
2. Once I've found the files, is there some way to get the info (like mp3 tags for example, that contain the artist and the song name etc.)?
   Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but Android already does that for you. For example, something along the [lines of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384080/mediastore-uri-to-query-all-types-of-files-media-and-non-media).

Comment: Use the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)

Comment: thanks, guys! This will definitely help! I obviously didn't mean for anybody to code an answer - just to point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
 String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
        Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
        File f = new File(path);        
        File file[] = f.listFiles();
        Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
        }
```

Also check this link:
http://javatechig.com/android/listing-all-sdcard-filenames-with-extensions-in-android

Comment: what is the advantage of using `Log.d` instead of some file that will store the data?

Comment: This is only to print and show you about the file names available there, you can also go through the link there. Thanks