# Download all type of image format in Android

Tags: android

I want to download images from server.I have tried with below code but **only .png** format images are download , remain **.jpeg, .gif, .bmp** etc are not. Can someone help me how to download all type of image format's in my Android Application.Thanks in advanced.

This is my Download method

```
void download_PngFile(String fileUrl)
    {
        Log.e("In download_PngFile ", " str_imgList_imageaudioPath = " + imageName);
        Bitmap imagenObtenida = null;
        try {
            URL ImgUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ImgUrl.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            imagenObtenida = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
            Log.e("imagenObtenida", " = " + imagenObtenida);

            String fotoname = imageName;
            File file = new File(newFolder, fotoname);
            int sizeOfImage = (int) file.length();
            Log.e("sizeOfImage "," = "+ sizeOfImage +"@ "+ imageName);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                imagenObtenida.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Log.e("Png = ","DownLoad complete");

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my another method which i checked in if condition images are ends with png, gif, bmp, and jpeg

```
public void getDoenLoaddata()
        {
            Log.e("Record is exists !!", " == ");
            //CreateFile();
            dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList", null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));
                    String strDownLoadStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status"));
                    //Log.e("imageName ", "  = " + imageName + " & strDownLoadStatus is " + strDownLoadStatus);
                    if (strDownLoadStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                    {
                        Log.e("Insert", " Status One");

                        if (imageName.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
                        {
                            String str_Mp3Url = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                            Log.e("str_ImageUrl#####", "  = " + str_Mp3Url);

                            download_Mp3File(str_Mp3Url);
                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }

                        if (imageName.endsWith(png_Pattern))
                        {
                            Log.e("imageName", " Status One" + imageName);
                            String str_ImageUrl = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                            Log.e("png_Pattern  ", " str_ImageUrl = " + str_ImageUrl);
                            download_PngFile(str_ImageUrl);

                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }

                        if (imageName.endsWith(jpg_pattern))
                        {
                            String str_Mp3Url = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                            Log.e("str_ImageUrl#####", "  = " + str_Mp3Url);

                            download_Mp3File(str_Mp3Url);
                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }

                        if (imageName.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
                        {
                            String str_Mp3Url = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                            Log.e("str_ImageUrl#####", "  = " + str_Mp3Url);

                            download_Mp3File(str_Mp3Url);
                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }

                        if (imageName.endsWith(gif_pattern))
                        {
                            String str_Mp3Url = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                            Log.e("str_ImageUrl#####", "  = " + str_Mp3Url);

                            download_Mp3File(str_Mp3Url);
                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }
                        if (imageName.endsWith(bmp_pattern))
                        {
                            String str_Mp3Url = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                            Log.e("str_ImageUrl#####", "  = " + str_Mp3Url);

                            download_Mp3File(str_Mp3Url);
                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (strDownLoadStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        // Log.e("Nothind To","Here !! ");
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } cursor.close();
            db1.close();
           /* db1.close();*/
    }
```

Comment: So you want to download all the images and query in the scard from them later or what exactly?

Comment: Did you copy-pasted  these codes from somewhere without reading them? The first explicitly says to save images in png format, the second downloads **images** with function named "Download_mp3file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to search and find your files based on the mimetyes.
At the following posts you can find help in querying images media and non-media using MediaStore and second when you want from a specific folder using again MediaStore class. 
1. [MediaStore - Uri to query all types of files (media and non-media)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384080/mediastore-uri-to-query-all-types-of-files-media-and-non-media). 
2. [Displaying images from a specific folder on the SDCard using a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039779/displaying-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-the-sdcard-using-a-gridview).