# How does one load .gif images from the Android Mediastore

Tags: android, image, gif, mediastore

i need to load a couple of gifs into a custom gallery view.
using the mediastore only provides me with png/jpg image types.
after a couple of hours googleing i still could not find the answer..

the code i use to load images from the mediastore is:

```
    final String sortOrder = mPreferences.getSortMode();

    final Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME };

    final Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, sortOrder);
```

thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try This, It may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384476/3778703)

use `String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("gif");`

instance of

```
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
```

from this ans.

Comment: this helped, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

this gave the perfect result.

```
private static final String[] COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST = new String[]
{
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.WIDTH,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.HEIGHT,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED
};

public void printGifUri(Context context)
{
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("gif");
    String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType };

    Cursor gifCursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST, selection,selectionArgsPdf,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

    gifCursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndexUri = gifCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    for (int i = 0; i < gifCursor.getCount(); i++)
        Log.d("gif file uri -> ", gifCursor.getString(columnIndexUri));
}
```

I prefer using Android [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html), as this loads the cursor in background and we get the result when finished.

```
public class GifListManagerImpl implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

Context mContext;

private static final String[] COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST = new String[]
{
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.WIDTH,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.HEIGHT,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED
};

public  GifListManagerImpl(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("gif");
    String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType };
    return new CursorLoader(mContext, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST, selection,selectionArgsPdf,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndexUri = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        Log.d("gif file uri -> ", cursor.getString(columnIndexUri));

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your directory containing your gifs is scanned by the media store in order to retrieve its content through the content provider.

check this link for more info:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/