# How can I share gif images to other app?

Tags: android

I am using glide to load GIF images into a RecyclerView.

```
Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl.trim())
                .asGif()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.coming)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(holder.gif_image);
```

Comment: @Tomm what happen???can you help me?

Comment: Have you opened the link i sended here

Comment: @Tomm what was that mean??? what do you want to say

Comment: Did you try to use Content Provider?

Comment: No @MaximTsybanov ,but how can I use it ???Do you have any idea??

Comment: Check info about Content Providers and this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37025082/1146533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your GIF image on web

```
 whatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    whatsappIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    whatsappIntent.setType("image/*");
                    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    new Download_GIF(image).execute();
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/downloadedFile.gif");
                    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                    try {
                        startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp"));
                            intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

here `whatsapp` is imageButton

Download_GIF class

```
public class Download_GIF extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    static String url_image=null;

    public Download_GIF(String url) {
        this.url_image = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String filepath = null;
        try {
            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            URL url = new URL(url_image);
            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();
            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.

            String filename = "downloadedFile.gif";   // you can download to any type of file ex:.jpeg (image) ,.txt(text file),.mp3 (audio file)
            Log.i("Local filename:", "" + filename);
            File file;
            file = new File(SDCardRoot, filename);
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                Log.i("Progress:", "downloadedSize:" + downloadedSize + "totalSize:" + totalSize);

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();
            if (downloadedSize == totalSize) filepath = file.getPath();

            //catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            filepath = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("filepath:", " " + filepath);

        return filepath;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it require to save the image first then share it???right now i am getting gif image's url from some api

Comment: you image is on web? or in local storage?

Comment: your need to download first if your gif is on web then your able to share it

Comment: But I can't understand how to save the gif images ,in case of jpeg or png etc we can do this by bitmap but I don't know how to save the gif ??

Comment: i already answer about how to save and share gif  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904028/8416317

Comment: Let me try your solution mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

you can't share gifs between android apps because there's not a protocol for that. 
sorry friend.

maybe if you want to share between apps built for you, you can serialize the image and a flag ( headers or another parameter )  to know it's a gif.