# How to list PDF in android 10 Api level 30?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0, android-11, scoped-storage

Google has restricted to access storage since android Q then how can we list all PDF files in recycler view?

Comment: What is the problem. How did you do it before?

Answer (score 0):

like this, just query all the files, and display the ones ending with ".pdf"
check the answer below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384476/13403911